# SharePoint Central Administration web access

Tags: 2010, central-administration

New to SharePoint and Server administration. I've deployed my SharePoint farm on a virtual PC. I am using Cloudshare. I can remotely access my team site over internet using external address but not central Administration. i tried with "externall address:port number".

Answer (score 1):

I believe that CloudShare blocks certain ports from external access. I suggest you open a support ticket from your CloudShare account management page. They are pretty good about getting back to you quickly. They should be able to tell you what ports are open for external access, and you may need to configure your Central Administration site to use an appropriate port. To do this will require a) setting the port in the IIS bindings for the Central Admin web application, and b) updating the alternate access mapping in Central Administration.

NOTE: I recommend getting Central Admin running on *both* your existing and the new port before removing the old port number.